# INT doesnt works in Apache POI

Tags: excel, excel-formula, java-8, apache-poi, xssf

i have a formula

```
=INT(RIGHT(input_pp_natal_limit,5))
```

in excel here `input_pp_natal_limit` value is "upto inner 5000" ,then RIGHT returns 5000 as string and finally answer evaluates to 5000 in excel. But when I evaluated this formula through `Apache POI`, It returned #value in error. I tried breaking this formulae then `apache POI` returned proper value till  RIGHT(input_pp_natal_limit,5). When I applied INT it returns #value in `apache POI`.

Please help me bypassing this error
`Apaache POI version -4.1.1 -Final`

Comment: please provide a runnable code, a java main

Comment: evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(calc.getRow(12).getCell(4)); im using evaluator on the formula u can reproduce it easily by replacing input_pp_natal_limit with string value "upto inner 5000"  in excel as =INT(RIGHT("upto inner 5,000",5)) .

Comment: with runnable code I mean: full java source you are using, smallest possible of course

Comment: This is one of the cases when `Microsoft` violates the own rules. [INT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef) requires a number as the argument. But `RIGHT` returns a text. `Excel` tolerates this but `apache poi` does not. `=INT(VALUE(RIGHT(input_pp_natal_limit,5)))` `apache poi` will be able to evaluate.

Comment: Hi Axel Richter , it worked flawlessly ..You've been a true guide in Apache POI.Thanks